# Smoothly animating new elements works from right but not from left

Tags: animation, d3.js

I created this without *too much* effort: http://jsfiddle.net/langdonx/J2ykT/1/

If you check the animate box, you'll see how elements phase in and out from the right very smoothly (excuse the bug if the random number generator gives you 0).

Now I'm trying to get elements to phase in from the left, but it appears that `selection.insert` doesn't insert elements as I anticipated.  You can see what I'm talking about here:

http://jsfiddle.net/wqPfR/

Both `1000` and `1001` get appended to the `div`, but when I insert `999` into my array, I would expect `.enter()` to provide me with `999`, but instead I get `1001` because it seems D3 only appends elements and re-indexes existing elements so-to-speak.

My problem is that I because of what I'll be displaying my `rect` elements, I can't afford to redraw each cell when a new element is created.

Am I just not able to use D3 for this technique, or is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, .data() is matching the existing elements by index. If you want them to be matched by value or by some internal property, you have to provide a function for this. In your example, this will work:

```
.data(data, function(d) { return d; });
```

From the [documentation for .data()](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#wiki-data):

> To control how data is joined to elements, a key function may be specified. This replaces the default by-index behavior; the key function is invoked once for each element in the new data array, and once again for each existing element in the selection.